# YAML exception: unacceptable character '' (0x0)

Tags: macos, upload, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This error appears on Elastic Beanstalk after uploading (with a zip) a new version to Elastic Beanstalk! with a file .ebextensions/singlehttps.config that sets the https for a single instance server.

Answer (score 23):

If you're doing the Amazon AWS workshop LAB:
https://github.com/awslabs/eb-node-express-signup

ie. Upload and Deploying your Elastic Beanstalk app

and getting this **PROBLEM** error:

*ERROR  Failed to deploy application.

*ERROR  The configuration file __MACOSX/.ebextensions/._setup.config in application version 1.1.0 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: unacceptable character '�' (0x0) special characters are not allowed in "", position 0, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (�) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.

*INFO   Environment update is starting.

**SOLUTION**

This is because MACOS includes some extra hidden folders which you need to exclude from your ZIP file. To do this, run this command in terminal on your zip:

```
$ zip -d nameofyourzipfile.zip __MACOSX/\*
```

Now re-upload, and you should get a success message:

INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.

Hope this solved your issue!

Comment: brilliant! this should be better documented on AWS' side

Comment: Didn't work for me :(
msolla@Mac-mini-de-Miguel php % zip -d gettingstarted.zip __MACOSX/\*
 zip warning: gettingstarted.zip not found or empty
 zip warning: name not matched: __MACOSX/*

zip error: Nothing to do! (gettingstarted.zip)

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this problem in the Elastic Beanstalk system was in fact in  the zip that is created in the Mac osx platform.
if you upload the new version with **eb deploy** command and not by zipping the application, then the problem doesn't appear!
Hope this helps someone, as it has been troubling me for so long!!

Comment: eb deploy command don't work for me:
msolla@Mac-mini-de-Miguel php % eb deploy GettingStartedApp-env
ERROR: NotFoundError - Environment "GettingStartedApp-env" not Found.

Answer (score 2):

When you zip folders on MACOSX, it will add its own hidden files in there alongside yours.

If you want to make a zip without those invisible Mac resource files such as “_MACOSX” or “._Filename” and .ds store files, use the “-X” option in the zip command

`$ zip -r -X archive_name.zip folder_to_compress`

If this is a pre-existing zip file, you can use the command others here have mentioned

`$ zip -d nameofyourzipfile.zip __MACOSX/\*`

Answer (score 0):

## Work around on Mac

Since it opens up the zip file and when you compress it, Elastic Beanstalk gives the error mentioned above. If you run command in previous comments to remove MACOSX related stuff, it still gave me an error about one of the files not found.

Workaround is that before doing the download, rename the zip file to some other extension and change to zip once its on the Mac.
When you upload this file to Elastic Beanstalk, it will work fine.